# Are questions of this sort considered acceptable?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics, asking-questions

For instance, say I wanted to ask a question about problems associated with the usage of Mathematics in studies of human behaviour (Economics, Psychology etc..)

Would this sort of question be welcomed, or is it better placed elsewhere?

If it is acceptable, which tags would you recommend?

Comment: Can you specify a little further what exactly the philosophical problem would be here? (Philosophy of math is definitely on point, if that helps clarify the line...)

Comment: For instance, neoclassical economics tries to be quite mathematical in its modelling of humans as rational agents.  Does the idea that we can reduce human behaviour to a model of rationality which can be represented mathematically, have any philosophical implications?

Comment: @Fivesigma That's on topic if you ask me. It's about philosophical implications of some theory. Where that theory comes from is not that important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the question.

Say the question is about applying math, like:

> How do I find the average income given a Lorenz curve?

Then clearly no: this should go to Economics, or even Math, if you can abstract the question from the particular economical context.

If it's a question about philosophy of science, for example:

> Is this falsification of that theorem correct?

Then, yes, but I don't think this is the type of question you're getting at.

Lately we have had some questions of the type:

> How can I be sure that this mathematical model represents that real life situation properly?

Which is borderline. In my opinion and experience, the best answers to those questions are found on other sites, where they deal with that specific field (economy, physics, etc.), but when phrased as a philosophical question it wouldn't be off topic here.

Note that for example Math and Physics have a soft-question tag which can be used for somewhat more meta level questions.

Comment: Thanks Keelan. My question would fit into the "How can I be sure..." bracket.